# How to turn off WinHttp proxy?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, proxy

Not too long ago I turned on a proxy for WinHttp traffic like this (from [this article](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-WinHTTP)):

```
netsh winhttp set proxy 127.0.0.1:8888
```

How can I turn the proxy off now?  I can't seem to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Open command prompt and enter the following commands:

```
netsh winhttp reset proxy
```

For details refer to this [technet article on netsh commands for WinHttp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731131%28WS.10%29.aspx)