# How to change the default `Using this proxyserver: 127.0.0.1:8888`?

Tags: windows, proxy, chocolatey

How to change the default `Using this proxyserver: 127.0.0.1:8888` instead of [resetting it](https://superuser.com/questions/558070/how-to-turn-off-winhttp-proxy)?

```
c:\Temp>choco install notepadplusplus
The default install location has been changed to 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey'.
  This install will be updated to that location in the next version. It
  is strongly suggested you move this installation to the new location
  as soon as possible to limit write access from all users. Do not forget
  to update PATH & ChocolateyInstall environment variables.
Chocolatey (v0.9.8.27) is installing 'notepadplusplus' and dependencies. By inst
alling you accept the license for 'notepadplusplus' and each dependency you are
installing.

notepadplusplus.install v6.6.8
Using this proxyserver: 127.0.0.1:8888
Write-Error : notepadplusplus did not finish successfully. Boo to the chocolate
y gods!
-----------------------
[ERROR] Exception calling "GetResponse" ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's using the proxy server that you have specified as your default.

If you are using fiddler, turn it off.

Comment: He wants to change it, he's not asking what it's using.

Comment: There is no default setting in chocolatey that sets the proxy server. If you have one set for use with internet, chocolatey will detect and use that one.

Comment: @ferventcoder After changing the Proxy server settings in IE (Tools > Internet Options > Connections > LAN settings > Proxy server: Use a proxy server ... Address: localhost Port: 8888) to `abcdef` and running the installation of a Chocolatey package, `Using this proxyserver: abcdef:8888` is displayed instead of `Using this proxyserver: 127.0.0.1:8888`. It seems that it could be changed by changing the default settings in IE. This works at home. On Monday I will check this at work as well and let you know the outcome. At home, turning of fiddler was not required.

Comment: @ferventcoder changing the proxy settings in IE to the proxy server the company is using solved the issue (+1). Thank you.